# How to switch between 2 forms using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've made a login screen. There's 2 forms inside one div. One containing login box, the other is for registration which is hidden in css by using display:none;. Below the login button there's a paragraph with a tag to click to register. How can I make it so when you click the a tag it just switches from login form to register form?

Im at the very begining stage if it comes to javascript.

```
<div class="login-page">
        <div class="form">
            <form class="register-form">
                <input type="text" placeholder="login"/>
                <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="e-mail"/>
                <button>create</button>
                <p class="message">Already have an account? <a href="#">Sign in!</a></p>
            </form>
            <form class="login-form">
                <input type="text" placeholder="login"/>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
                    <button>Sign in</button>
                    <p class="message">Need an account? <a href="#">Register!</a></p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So here's what I've found on codepen but I can't get it to work on my website:

```
<script> $('.message a').click(function(){$('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");}); </script>
```

Comment: That script uses jQuery (a very common JS library). Do you have jQuery loaded in your page?

Comment: Yes, this is from my <head>    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: Perhaps I did something wrong including the script itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason that your script may not work is if you included it within the `<head>...</head>` of the document instead of just before the closing `</body>` tag.

The reason the script would have failed in this case is due to the `<body>...</body>` not being loaded when your script runs. Check for any errors in your browser's console.

Another reason is perhaps you loaded jQuery *after* your custom script. For example:

```
<script>...</script>
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

instead of:

```
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>...</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, that did it!!! Thank you so much. I was including it at the begining of body tag. I placed it right before </body> and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Add some css to hide the login form.

```js
$('.message a').click(
  function() {
    $('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
  }
 );
```

```css
.login-form {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="login-page">
    <div class="form">
        <form class="register-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="login"/>
            <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
            <input type="text" placeholder="e-mail"/>
            <button>create</button>
            <p class="message">Already have an account? <a href="#">Sign in!</a></p>
        </form>
        <form class="login-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="login"/>
                <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
                <button>Sign in</button>
                <p class="message">Need an account? <a href="#">Register!</a></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```